# Passar String para matriz (Xml);

Tags: java, xml

Eu estou usando Esse código para ler um mapa de um aquivo xml.

```
private void loadMap(String mapa) {

        File file = new File(getClass().getResource(mapa).getFile());

        try {

            dbBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
            org.w3c.dom.Document doc  = dbBuilder.parse(file);

            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("layer");

            for(int i=0; i<nList.getLength(); i++) {

                Node node = nList.item(i);
                if(node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element element = (Element) node;

                     // Le o conteudo
                    String conteudo = element.getElementsByTagName("data").item(0).getTextContent();

                }
            }

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

O arquivo seria esse:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<map version="1.0" tiledversion="1.0.2" orientation="orthogonal" renderorder="right-down" width="42" height="34" tilewidth="16" tileheight="16" nextobjectid="1">
 <tileset firstgid="1" name="tileset" tilewidth="16" tileheight="16" tilecount="924" columns="33">
  <image source="tileset.png" trans="003bff" width="528" height="448"/>
 </tileset>
 <layer name="Camada de Tiles 1" width="42" height="34">
  <data encoding="csv">
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,661,662,663,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,694,695,696,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,666,667,668,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,699,700,701,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,732,733,734,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,765,766,767,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,666,667,668,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,699,700,701,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,34,34,34,34,34,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,34,34,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,34,34,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,265,266,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,34,34,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,298,299,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,34,34,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
</data>
 </layer>
</map>
```

Mas eu não consegui passar  o conteudo para uma matriz. `mapa[34][42];` , Alguém sabe uma maneira de fazer isso?

Answer (score 1):

Bem, quem estiver com o mesmo problema, consegui fazer assim:

```
public void loadMap(String path) {

        File file = new File(getClass().getResource(path).getFile());

        try {

            DocumentBuilder dbBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc  = dbBuilder.parse(file);

            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("layer");

            for(int i=0; i<nList.getLength(); i++) {

                Node node = nList.item(i);
                if(node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element element = (Element) node;

                    String conteudo = element.getElementsByTagName("data").item(0).getTextContent();

                    String[] partes = conteudo.split("\\s+");

                    String regex = ",";
                    for(int row=0; row < altura; row++) { // map Height
                        String[] linha = partes[row + 1].substring(0, partes[row + 1].length()).split(regex);
                        for(int col=0; col < largura; col++) { // map Width
                            int numero = Integer.parseInt(linha[col].trim());
                            mapa[row][col] = (numero - 1);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```